# How to save data entered in a bootstrap modal into another model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to create a django based load-requirement matching web-app which takes "Load details" in a model called *ShipperBoardModel* where people(manufacturers) post that they want certain items to be delivered somewhere, and other people(called transporters) who bid on those posts, that they can get that job done, for their chosen price.

ShipperBoardModel

```
class ShipperBoardModel(models.Model):
  From = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
  To = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
  Type = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
  Length = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
  Weight = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
  Numberoftrucks = models.IntegerField(null=True)
  MaterialType = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=100)
  Loadingtime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

def _str_(self):
    return self.Origin
```

I created the first 'loads' table where many people posted their loads on it, and this is being displayed on a page "/loads/" where it shows all active loads available for bidding.

[image]

I added a "Bid now" button next to every row, clicking on which opens a form which asks the transporters what price they are willing to bid for that particular load/task.

On clicking 'Bid now', we get a pre-filled form in a bootstrap modal relative to the row it is in. **Then, a transporter enters his bid for that task/load, which I want to save into another model called *'SupplierBidModel'*.**

I just want to figure out how to save that bid price, into that model, along with the BidID, and the transporterID which every transporter already has when they registered.

Here is the form, followed by the model:

[image]

```
class SupplierBidModel(models.Model):
    BidID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Load_ID = models.OneToOneField(ShipperBoardModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Supplier_ID = models.OneToOneField(SupplierBoardModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Bid_amount = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

I have some data saved in my models.py, and using that model I am rendering a table. Now, for each row I want the user to enter a single entry, which should save that data into another model.

Here is the template :

```
{% block content %}
    <table>
        {% for item in data %}

            <tr>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
                <th>Weight</th>
                <th>Length</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Material Type</th>
                <th>Number of Trucks</th>
                <th>Loading Time</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item.From }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.To }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.Weight }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.Length }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.Type }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.MaterialType }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.Numberoftrucks }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.Loadingtime }}</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{ item.id }}">Bid
                        now! for id {{ item.id }} </button>
                </td>
                {#        {% endfor %}#}


                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{ item.id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">

                                <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text"
                                       placeholder="Disabled input here..." value="{{ item.To }}" disabled>
                                <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text"
                                       placeholder="Disabled input here..." value="{{ item.From }}" disabled>
                                <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text"
                                       placeholder="Disabled input here..." value="{{ item.Weight }}" disabled>
                                <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text"
                                       placeholder="Disabled input here..." value="{{ item.Length }}" disabled>
                                <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text"
                                       placeholder="Disabled input here..." value="{{ item.Type }}" disabled>
                                <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text"
                                       placeholder="Disabled input here..." value="{{ item.MaterialType }}" disabled>
                                <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text"
                                       placeholder="Disabled input here..." value="{{ item.Numberoftrucks }}" disabled>
                                <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text"
                                       placeholder="Disabled input here..." value="{{ item.Loadingtime }}" disabled>
                                <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text"
                                       placeholder="Disabled input here...">Bid
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

{% endblock %}
```

I do not yet know how to render a form, on a page in django, where there exists a form already. The only way to render form I know of, is using the urls.py method :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'supplier', views.supplierboardfun, name='supplierboard'),
    url(r'shipper', views.shipperboardfun, name='shipperboard'),
    url(r'loads', views.suppliertablefun, name='supplierboardtable')
]
```

which calls the function suppliertablefun()

```
def suppliertablefun(request):                     # function to display shipperboardmodel
    data = ShipperBoardModel.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'supplierboard/board.html', locals())
```

I am probably missing on how to render a multiple forms with different models in django, or how to save data from an input box, and save it to the model of my liking along with some relative information.

Comment: you should add form to the your modal and put all inputs inside it, and create view which will processing the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was able to do it as such

```
def suppliertablefun(request):                     # function to display shipperboardmodel
    data = ShipperBoardModel.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        forminput = BiddingForm(request.POST)
        if forminput.is_valid():
            forminput.save()

    forminput = BiddingForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'supplierboard/board.html', locals(),{'forminput': forminput})
```